# How do I react to Facebook API Graph deprecation warning?

Tags: ios, facebook

Our iOS app uses official iOS Facebook SDK (latest version) to handle user login and getting user friends. This is the only way of interaction with Facebook platform. We do not make any direct HTTP requests to Graph API, etc.

But when I open Facebook developer portal, I get a warning: "API Graph v2.8 will be deprecated on Apr 18, 2019 ...".

How shall I react to it? I checked that API Graph integrated into the Facebook SDK is later than 2.8. Can I safely ignore the warning then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as you don´t use any features that are deprecated with v2.8, you can ignore it:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/changelog/

...and if the SDK uses a newer version, you are safe anyway.